# Puppeteer - Get element by xPath

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

Hi I've been searching everywhere for a very simple explanation on how to find an element by xPath.

All I want is a simple approach to finding an element but instead all the help I manage to find requires doing a `page.evaluate()`. Which doesn't work for me. Here's what i'm trying to do:

Load a URL > Wait until page fully loads (Spinner stops moving) > Find an `<input>` element given the xpath.

Here's my code:

```
          await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

          console.log("Page Loaded");

          let loggedIn = await page.evaluate(() => {

            let emailInput = document.evaluate("//input[@type='email' and @placeholder='Email address']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

            return{
              emailInput
            }

          });
          
          console.log(loggedIn);
```

Instead of getting the element, i get null when i do `waitUntil : 'load'`

and I get undefined when i do `waitUntil : 'networkidle0'`

Is there a simplier way to get elements? Maybe something like....

`page.getElementByXPATH(xpath)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `page.evaluate()` can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). As `document.evaluate()` returns one or more DOM elements that are not serializable (they contain methods and circular references), this elements is replaced with an empty object or undefined. You need to return either serializable value (for example, a text, attribute or array/object of them) or use something like [`page.$x(xpath)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) and more complicated [`ElementHandle` API](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle).